# Prove uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n}(1-x^{n})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series, uniform-convergence

I need to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n}(1-x^{n})$ converges for $x \in (-1,1]$. Also, I need to prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n}(1-x^{n})$ converges uniformly for $x \in (-1+\delta,1-\delta)$ such that $0<\delta<\frac{1}{2}$. Here's my trial:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n}(1-x^{n}) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n}- x^{2n}\\
& = (x - x^{2}) + (x^{2} - x^{4}) + (x^{3} - x^{6}) + ...\\
 &= x + x^{3} + x^{5} + ...\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{2n-1}\\
&= \frac{x}{1-x^2}  
\end{align*}
With the above result, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n}(1-x^{n})$ converges for $x \in (-1,1)$ (but not for $x=1$). I'm open to any ideas for uniform convergence.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What is $(1+\delta, 1-\delta)$ if $\delta>0$? Is $x$ in this interval or rather in $(-1,1]$? Could you please clarify your problem? Also, please show us your attempt.

Comment: At $x=1$, your series is identically $0$, i.e., it converges. Thus it converges to a discontinuous function on $(-1,1]$, i.e., the convergence cannot be uniform on $(-1,1]$.

Comment: To follow up @Gary's comment: when you get singular behavior in a simplification, it's possible that convergence can still happen outside of that region. You need to plug the endpoints directly into the original series to see if they converge.

Comment: Thank you! So the series indeed converges for $x \in (-1,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the uniform convergence part, use the Weierstrass M-test:

> Suppose that $f_n$ is a sequence of real or complex valued functions defined on a set $A$, and that there is a sequence of non-negative numbers $M_n$ satisfying the conditions $|f_{n}(x)|\leq M_{n}$ for all  $n\geq 1$ and all  $x\in A$, and
> $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } M_{n}$ converges.
> Then the series $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }f_{n}(x)$$
> converges absolutely and uniformly on A. (Source: Wikipedia)

To find a sequence $M_n$ in your problem, we have for all $x \in (-1+\delta, 1-\delta
)$,

$$ |f_n(x)|=|x^n (1-x^n)| \leq 2\,|x^n| \leq 2\,(1-\delta)^n,$$

and the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-\delta)^n $ converges to $\frac{1}{\delta}$. Therefore by the Weierstrass M-test the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n (1-x^n)$ converges uniformly on that interval.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!